# How to know where database has changed

Tags: django, django-database

I have a project that looks like a simple shopping site that sells different kinds of products. For example, I have 4 models: `Brand`, `Product`, `Consignment`. `Consignment` is linked to `Product`, and `Product` is linked to `Brand`. To reduce count of queries to databases, I want to save current state of these models(or at least some of them). I want to do it, because I show a sidebar with brands and products. So every time when user opens some page, it will execute the query to database to get those brands and products. 
But when `admin` add some new product or brand, I want to handle database changing and resave it. How to implement it?

Comment: please elaborate more, you can use post_save and pre_save signal, they will hit each time some thing is changed

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is by using Cache. Cache is a method to store your objects in memory/other app like redis temporarily so that you do not need send queries to database. You can read the full description [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/).

Or, you can use this [third party library that helps you to cache Django ORM Model.](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops) Here are the example.

```
Brand.objects.filter(name='stackoverlow').cache()
```

After doing an update to the model, you need to `clear` or `invalidate` the cache.

```
invalidate_model(Brand)
```